# Dynamics CRM 2013: Reordering Custom Record Sitemap Tiles

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am having issues finding how to reorder the tiles on a sitemap for a specific record.

This is view is accessed by clicking on a specific custom entity record and by selecting the down arrow on the sitemap.

Here is a screenshot of the tiles I want to reorder
[image]

Please let me know if there is any confusion in the question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the list of the related entities of the record.

To change the order:
1) Open the form editor to edit the form
2) Click the "Navigation" button on the top ribbon (in the middle, between "body" and "business rules"). The navigation (on the left) is now editable
3) Drag & Drop the icons of the related entities (top of the list = left of the ribbon).
4) Save
5) Publish
6) Refresh open pages

You can also hide the related entities: click on the name > press "delete" key or change the "display" options of the relations (solution > entity > 1:N or N:1 or N:N).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I am able to move the Connections and Audit, but seems I am having difficulties moving the Activities and Closed Activities. Do you know how I would move these two tiles?

Comment: I don't think you can move those. I'm afraid some system relationships cannot be edited...